# Skipping because it does not denote a directory

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Every time I start my Spring Boot application I receive a warning saying `Skipping [/opt/xxx/yyy.war] because it does not denote a directory`.

Actually I found that error report on [Spring Git Hub](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2825), but was on JSP application because it was in development mode, and probably solved on Spring Boot 1.3.3 than you could configure it on application properties.

I updated the Spring Boot, made the configuration setting the parameter `server.jsp-servlet.init-parameters.development=false`, but not solved.

This cause some performance issue on the system, any ideia?

Comment: Something's asking Spring Framework to find matching resources in a  particular directory, but is passing in a `File` that points to a war rather than to a directory. Can you share a sample that reproduces the warning?

Comment: See when I ran the project with `mvn spring-boot:run` that error not throws, but if I ran with `java -jar myproject.war` than it shows up. I don't know if it helps but I'm not pretty sure what sample I can sent to you.

Comment: Any small sample that produces the error would be useful. I've just tried it with a simple executable war and it did not produce the warning message.

Comment: Andy thanks a lot for your attention, and when I cleaned up the project to send you only the executable application I solved just updating the spring-boot to the 1.3.2 version.